# Why is the PopupControlExtender generating a full postback inside an UpdatePanel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a button inside an updatepanel. I have a PopupControlExtender linked to the button so when the button is clicked a panel pops up. It works fine except it does a full postback and I can't figure out why. The button and the PopupControlExtender is inside an update panel which inside the ContentTemplate tag. When I take out the PopupControlExtender the button only does a partial postback. I'm having trouble finding any useful information on the PopupControlExtender. Do I have to declare a postback trigger or something?

Edit: If I use a LinkButton control it generates a partial postback. Seems to only do the full postback with a Button control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure the button's UseSubmitBehavior property is set to false

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact opposite issue: the Link Button causes a full post-back while the Button control works. However unlike the other answer, the Button only works if UseSubmitBehavior is True/undefined.

So I just use some CSS with the button to it look like a link button, e.g.

```
input.linkButton
{
    background-color: transparent;
    border-style: none;
    color: #0000FF;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: underline; 
}
```

(Thanks to Englestone's blog for that one).